# How to read XSLT list item of a list view web part in SharePoint designer 2010 using jquery

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a requirement to get data from one list(e.g., A) and display in some other list's (e.g. B) custom display form(e.g. CustomDispForm.aspx).

Here I am going to do this with the help of jQuery SP Services using `GetListItems()`. For getting the data I need to pass two parameters from list(B), but the data is like `<xsl:value-of select="@testField_"/>` .

I have stuck how to pass such variables in jQuery function.
Please let me know how to achieve this.